# Extract name of files in a compressed file (.7z) using python

Tags: python, compression, 7zip

I want to know the name of files inside of a compressed file (7zip) without extracting that file. How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1):

On Mac or Linux you could use [libarchive](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/). (On windows you can try [libarchive-c](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive-c/) but I have never tried it)

Here's a rough example to get you started, though I suggest you read the link

```
import libarchive.public

with libarchive.public.file_reader('test.7z') as e:
    for entry in e:
         print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Linux example, if you're just writing a quick script ( no worries about deformed filenames coming from untrusted users ) you could always just defer to the 7z executeable ( this code assumes yours supports the undocumented -ba option )

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# this doesn't work for files with embedded newlines

import subprocess
import sys

pp = subprocess.run(
    [ '7z', 'l', '-ba', sys.argv[1] ] ,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE ,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE ,
)

pp.check_returncode()

for line in pp.stdout.split( b'\n' ):
    if line:
        sys.stdout.buffer.write( line[53:] )
        sys.stdout.buffer.write( b'\n' )
```